# Converting of string type to date parse not working

Tags: java

I am converting the string type to date and parsing it to a HH:mm format but while formatting its not working throwing exception,campusconfig.getworktime() is date Below is my code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            if ((from1 != null)) {
                if(campusConfig.getWorkFromTime()!=null){
                String time = "";
                Date timech;
                time = campusConfig.getWorkFromTime().toString();
                timech = dateFormat.parse(time);

                if(from1.before(timech)){
                    String errormsg = message.getString("message.reports.time.select.campustime");
                    errorMessageUI(errormsg);
                }
```

Comment: what exception? what is your input?

Answer (score 0):

If campusConfig contains a full date (date and time) you need to parse it with SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS") (with the correct format) then you can trasform the date in only time with other SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") format(date).

Sample:

```
public class DateFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String campusConfig = "2015-11-26 11:46:20";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf_in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d = sdf_in.parse(campusConfig);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf_out = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        System.out.println("Only Time : " + sdf_out.format(d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like below,

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(campusConfig.getWorkFromTime().toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks @ziaurmca.But this will be return type string.i need return type as date

Comment: Date object do not have any format. i.e. you can not convert any Date object into perticular format. 
Becuase it has its own string format which will return when you print any date. You can convert any string format only.

You can convert or construct any Date Object from date string of the specific format. 
but that date object will not be in a specific format.A Java Date is a container for the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

When you use something like System.out.println(date), Java uses Date.toString() to print the contents.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").parse("2012-07-10 14:58:00.000000");
```

Comment: Ya i need only in HH:mm format.why parse showing exception.

Comment: Unparseable date  Thu Jan 01 09:00:00 IST 1970 like this showing.In this i need only HH:mm